# insertar imagenes usando la libreria de DOCX javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy generando un documento de word pero al usar imagenes si las agrega pero no las muestra de esta forma[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy usando esta libreria `https://docx.js.org` pero hasta el momento no eh tenido resultado alguno

esto llevo de codigo

```
 const logo = new docx.ImageRun({
            data:Uint8Array.from(atob( btoa(response['image'])),c=>c.charCodeAt(0)),
                transformation:{
                    width:100,
                    height:100,
                },
            });
            const doc = new docx.Document({
                sections:[{
                    children:[
                        new docx.Paragraph({
                            children:[
                                logo
                            ]
                        })
                    ],
                }]
            })
        docx.Packer.toBlob(doc).then((blob) => {
            saveAs(blob, "example.docx");
        });
```